# How can I push surrounding elements off screen when enlarging one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a group of elements in two columns, when you click on one it should expand and push all of the other ones out of the way. Like going from A to B.

**A** [image]  **B** [image]

I have explicitly created two columns then filled them. When you click on an element in the left column, it expands, which pushes the stuff below it down, and the column on the right is supposed to move more right so that it is partially hidden off screen. The problems are that the elements above aren't pushed up, and the right column, is pushed below the left column, and then pushed right. 
You can see the results here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/easilyBaffled/RJ8Q3/).

It is strange because the right column starts moving right a bit, then moves down, and then finishes moving right. If I don't explicitly set the right column to `left: 270px;` it will just be pushed below. I have tried to lock it's y position by setting `top: 5px;` but it keeps getting forced down. How can I make the elements move as I want them to?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="col left">
        <div class="elem">x</div>
        <div class="elem">x</div>
        <div class="elem">x</div>
    </span>
    <span class="col right">
        <div class="elem">x</div>
        <div class="elem">x</div>
        <div class="elem">x</div>
    </span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    height: 400px;
    width: 330px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.elem {
    height: 60px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 5px 5px;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 2s ease;    
}
.col{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all 2s ease;
}
.expand {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px 10px;
}
.push{
    left: 270px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
 $(".elem").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("expand");
        $(".right").addClass("push");
    });
```

Comment: The right column cannot go to the right because by default the whole element should be visible. If it is not visible it goes down to another line.

Comment: But doesn't overflow: hidden in the container fix that? Also it does go to the right, it just is pushed down first

Comment: What happens to the top box when two elements in the same column are "inflated"?

Comment: the top box in the column stays where it is, the two elements are pushed down, and the right column is pushed further down.

Comment: `"the elements above aren't pushed up"` means you will need either absolute positioning (and position everything like Isotope does), or you will need to sync it with `scrollTop` movement. Given what you are trying to do, you may want to look at isotope or start laying them out *positioned absolutely*.

Comment: Next question: what happens when two boxes in the same column are 'inflated'?

Comment: The container width is messing this up. Remove the container width and change .push to margin-left: 20px;  http://jsfiddle.net/RJ8Q3/2/

Comment: Added an answer below that corrects the first negative margin to match the number of items above the one clicked. Gives the effect *I think* you wanted. might need to tweak the margin value as you lose the first margin completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/RJ8Q3/12/

I removed the .push css, added `white-space:nowrap;`, added `vertical-align:top;`, added class `.WithLarge` to container and added `margin-top:-20px;` to it.

`Margin-top` solves the transition and `is(":first-child")` solves clicking the first element.

Javascript

```
$(".elem").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("expand");
    if (!$(this).is(":first-child"))
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("WithLarge");
});
```

CSS

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    height: 400px;
    width: 330px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.col{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all 2s ease;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.WithLarge{
    margin-top:-20px;  
}
```

Comment: Even better, no extra mark-up required, nicely spotted.

Comment: I like the solution, but right column is still being pushed down a bit, can you explain why?

Comment: Need some time to stay it on top.

Comment: If you click on the middle or bottom elements, *the item(s) above it should move up*.

Comment: Hm. It is not that easy. I'll try.

Comment: @EasilyBaffled: It jumps up and down instantly (at least in Chrome).

Answer (score 1):

if you want the right element to move right without moving down do this:

### css

```
.col {
 position:absolute;
}
.right {
    left:170px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RJ8Q3/3/)

Comment: He wants the clicked element to remain stationary and the *items above to move up*. Needs a little something extra :)

Comment: Negative margins will need to be relative shifts, as they vary based on how many items you clicked on.

Comment: I tried adding  margin: -10px 10px 10px 10px; to expand in your example, the clicked box expands up, but overlaps, not pushes the box above.

Comment: your negative margin needs to be calculated in relation to the resized div.. I'll try to make this work..

Comment: try this: http://jsfiddle.net/RJ8Q3/7/... adding this to the javascript is a start, but more is definitely needed.

Answer (score 1):

### Simplified it to this: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/RJ8Q3/11/

```
$(".elem").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass("expand").parent().children().first().css({"margin-top": -10 * $this.index()-1});
    $(".right").addClass("push");
});
```

*Note: *You may need to tweak the calcuation to ensure the first margin is what you expect.*

Old version: Try something like this:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/RJ8Q3/8/

```
$(".elem").click(function () {
    var $prior = $(this).addClass("expand").prevAll();
    $(this).parent().children().first().css({"margin-top": -10 * $prior.length});
    $(".right").addClass("push");
});
```

*I know this can be simplified, but I was in a rush.*

`$prior.first()` did not select the item I expected  (not sure why), but this one worked.